# Is it possible to invoke OS commands from a NASL script in OpenVAS?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, nessus, openvas

I was wondering if it is possible to run a command like `cat`, `w3m` or any other Operating System (Linux) utility from inside a NASL script and use its output. Do you know any examples? I know you can use the tools that OpenVAS uses like nikto, etc because they are already builtin functions. But can you use other tools that are not part of OpenVAS directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the NASL function `pread` which allows you to run external commands from within a NASL script. An example to run `cat` and get its output could be:

```
args = make_list( "cat", # The cmd which is called, needs to be in cmd as well
                  "/etc/passwd" );
ret = pread( cmd:"cat",  # The command to run
             argv:args,  # The arguments list of above
             cd:FALSE ); # This specifies if a `cd` to the directory of the `cmd`should be done
```

A "full" example with various code path (e.g. checking if the command exists before running it) can be found in e.g. `nikto.nasl` (http://plugins.openvas.org/nasl.php?oid=14260)

Comment: the link above is broken, is there a new web-based home for the OpenVAS NASL repository?

Comment: I'm not aware of any new official web-based home. You might find some 3rdparty sources / GitHub repository or check the file on a current feed of a relevant installation.